# Solr configset Underlying core creation failed while creating collection

Tags: solr

I've made a custom configset based on *sample_techproducts_configs* where I just edit the fields that will be used.

But, when i want to create collection with it, I have this error :

```
Failed to create collection 'collectionName' due to : Underlying core creation failed while
creating collection: collectionName
```

I have the same error both with visual API or the terminal.

Do you have any idea?

Thx

Comment: The Solr log should give you the actual reason why the creation failed.

Comment: Hi @MatsLindh, the logs note that I have to upload the configset in trusted mode. Do you know how I do this?

Comment: [See the explanation in the reference manual](https://lucene.apache.org/solr/guide/8_5/configsets-api.html#configsets-upload)

Comment: Try changing SOLR_OPTS="$SOLR_OPTS -Dsolr.allowPaths=*" in solr.in.sh / solr.in.cmd. This worked for the same issue in solr 8.6.  Please note that * will allow all paths, you can put the needed path accordingly.

Comment: It was a problem of authentication.

Comment: Hi @Brandys can you add your solution as an answer here?
I think Im facing the same issue as yours.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Problem solved when you upload the configset as authenticated user.

```
curl -u 'user:Password' ... the rest of the command.
```